# How to put a caller of write of a character device driver kernel module to sleep

Tags: c, linux-kernel, blocking

I created a character device driver kernel module in Linux as described in [this fabulous tutorial](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x579.html). The driver works well, but I need to extend the kernel module function

```
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off)
```

so that a calling user process (which calls the function [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)) is blocked for a fixed time.

I could include `linux/delay.h` and use `msleep(1000)` in the function `device_write` in my kernel module to let the CPU wait. But I don't know if that is the right way to block the function call of `write()` in the user space.

*Please don't confuse this with concurrent access to resources. That's not my point here. I only want to block the `write()` call of the user space program until I have the data written to my hardware device which takes some time. Only after this I know if the operation was successful and I can return an appropriate status call through `device_write` to the `write` call of the user space program.*

Comment: So you are "guessing" when the operation is complete?

Comment: Hint: if you want to figure out how to do something, find an existing mechanism which does something generally similar, and look at how it works.  You seem to be describing an extremely ordinary blocking I/O driver so should have no trouble finding comparable examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use down_interruptible(struct semaphore), inside the blocking function, and release the semaphore in some other kernel thread / event handler, thus releasing the calling thread.